# MySQLi Error: addcslashes() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, laravel

I have this piece of code which produces the following error:

> Warning: addcslashes() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in line 10

My code is:

```
$searchtype = isset($_POST['searchtype']) ? $_POST['searchtype'] : null;
$searchterm = isset($_POST['searchterm']) ? $_POST['searchtype'] : null;
$searchterm = trim($searchterm);
if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
    echo 'You are not entered search detail. Please go back and try again';
}
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $searchtype = addcslashes($searchtype);//line 10 with error
    $searchterm = addcslashes($searchterm);//line with error
}
@ $db = new msqli('localhost','root','','sales');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again leter.';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: ok, and the problem is?

Comment: seems the easiest fix is just to use `addslashes` instead of `addCslashes`.. but yes the C version does indeed require 2 parameters

Comment: i will suggest you to read `prepared statements` and use it. No need of `escape` and `addslashes`

Answer (score 0):

Like your error says, you must use two parameters to `addcslashes` like this:

```
addcslashes($searchtype,"W");
```

See:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addcslashes.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need a second param which is a list of char you want to escape. For example :

```
echo addcslashes("Hello world", array("l")); // => He\l\lo wor\ld
```

[Here is more information about this very topic](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are using method `addcslashes` that requires 2 arguments as stated in on http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php

Possibly You were looking for `addslashes($searchtype)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `addslashes` instead of `addcslashes` and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same situation and needed to have the same keys in both arrays, so I ended up doing it that way, and it worked well for me:

```
let jsarray = {
              <?php
                foreach ($phparray as $key => $value) {
                  echo $key.':'.'"'.addslashes($value).'",';
                }
              ?>
            };
```